# How does deleting a vector value directly cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two scenarios

```
Object* obj = Vector[0];
delete obj;
```

Versus

```
delete Vector[0];
```

I’m told the later causes memory leak and array out of bounds. How? Doesn’t both methods point to the same pointer?

Comment: If `Vector` contains raw pointers, the effect is the same. Where did you hear this? However, you should set `Vector[0] = nullptr` afterwards and ensure that the pointed object is not accessed by testing for nullptr.

Comment: if `Vector[0]` evaluates to a `Object*`, then there shouldn't be any difference in the behavior of the program.

Comment: It does not cause a memory leak. It causes a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: Please clarify the type of `Vector` and how the objects that are to be deleted were created. The current answers are already diverging on the the interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Vector is an `std::vector<Object*>`, both versions are absolutely the same and absolutely fine. As long as your vector actually has an element and you don't try to read Vector[0] afterwards.

Comment: Mostly correct, except "reading" `Vector[0]` afterwards is fine. What one musn't do is indirect through the pointer. Also, `Vector[0]` must have been returned from allocating `new` for it to be fine.